# Reusing the types from the DjangoObjectType in the graphene

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have created the PreferencesNode from the DjangoObjectType which contains the gateway provider as TextChoices.

```
class GatewayProvider(models.TextChoices):
    STRIPE = "stripe", "Stripe"
    RAZORPAY = "razorpay", "Razorpay"
```

```
class PreferencesNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Preferences
        exclude_fields = ("user_id",)
```

Now I want to use `AccountPreferencesGatewayProviderChoices` enum (created via `PreferencesNode`). How can I do this?

Currently I am creating another enum inheriting `graphene.Enum`.

```
class GatewayProviderEnum(graphene.Enum):
    STRIPE = GatewayProvider.STRIPE.value
    RAZORPAY = GatewayProvider.RAZORPAY.value
```

But this is creating redundant enum type.

[image: output from the graphiql]

Here I am asking the question. How can I use the `AccountPreferencesGatewayProviderChoices` enumeration which is created through DjangoObjectType, in the different mutation or query as argument **without redefining the type**?

Comment: How can I use the `AccountPreferencesGatewayProviderChoices` enumeration which is created through DjangoObjectType, in the different mutation or query as argument **without redefining the type**?